# Ending response when knex throws an error using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, knex.js

I'm getting "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" this error in my api. I understand that I'm sending response back multiple times which causes the problem, but i'm not sure how to fix it.

The error occurs when a knex error happens in the first db call `res.status(500)` which returns/sends the response to the client. The problem is I'm not sure how to end the code there or should I even end it at all? I know I could probably chain my promises so this doesn't occur but I believe it would be cleaner in the end with async/await.

I'm currently forcing my code to go to the catch block in the first database call. And I know that the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" errors occurs when I return/send `res.sendStatus(200)`.

What is a good solution to this problem?

```
   let existingUser = await knex('user').where({ username }).orWhere({ email }) // <-- first db call
      .then(([user]) => user)
      .catch(() => res.status(500))

    if (!existingUser) {
      knex('user').insert({
        username,
        password_digest,
      }) // <-- second db call
        .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
        .catch(() => res.sendStatus(500))
    } else {
      return () => res.sendStatus(409)
    }
```

Thanks in advance Stackoverflow community!

Comment: Don't call `res.status(500)` in the catch block at the start. You are already handling the case of the user not already existing further down.

Comment: But what if theres a database error? Shouldn't there be some handling whenever I call the database?

Comment: Handling the error is fine, but handling it with `res.status(500)` isn't (because you're creating a user and calling `res.status(200)` later)

Comment: Can you give me some recommendations on how I can handle the first catch and line 3 without ```res.status(500)```?

Comment: Well, what about `.catch(() => console.log("user doesn't exist yet"))`? Again, you're creating the user if it isn't found. So why would you return status 500 *and* status 200? Pick one.

Comment: `if (!existingUser) {` when is `existingUser` going to be false(y)?

Comment: Chris G: The solution works, but would'nt there be a slight chance that the code will fail? For example, user does exist in the database but the database call fails resulting in a ```console.log('error')```. Code will then insert a new user which should not happen. Yes there is a unique constraint, but what if that fails as well? According to knex docs, the unique constraint - "On Amazon Redshift, this constraint is not enforced, but it is used by the query planner." Sorry, being a little too detailed haha but just what if?

Jaramanda X: ```existingUser``` will be false if user doesnt exist.

Comment: If you want to catch the query failing, you need to `await` the query itself and catch that, then simply check if `queryResult[0]` exists in the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a try-catch block rather than `.then`, `.catch`. It makes it easier to understand what the code is doing, just like async/await.

Here is an example:

```
try {
    let existingUser = await knex('user').where({ username }).orWhere({ email }).first()

    if (!existingUser) {
      await knex('user').insert({
        username,
        password_digest,
      })

      return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      return res.sendStatus(409)
    }
} catch (error) {
    return res.sendStatus(500)
}
```

You will jump down to the catch block if an error is thrown in the try block.

I haven't tested this particular snippet, so please tell me if it doesn't work.